# Bind Qt with QtGStreamer

Tags: c++, qt, voip, qtgstreamer

I am trying to make a simple qt c++ VoIP application, when I searched I found the QtGStreamer Lib and wanted to make it work. I download the latest version 1.2 from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/qt-gstreamer/).
When I went to the example folder and tried to compile the VoIP example I got this error: 
`Qt5GStreamer-1.0 development package not found`

What I try is comment this line `CONFIG += link_pkgconfig` in .pro file and add the src folder that came with the folder of QtGstreamer to folder project. I also added this to .pro file 
 `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/src` this the path of the Libs folder

Now I get an error that i need to add boost Lib so I add it by adding this to .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_1_61_0
LIBS += "-LC:/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib"
```

Now I get many errors that say (undefined reference to ..) 130 error. Not sure what to try. 
the file comes with containing Readme file I download the dependency but the same error I think the problem that I don't link it correctly 
I'm still a beginner in 3rd party and link libs in c++,
my os is windows
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the README in the root directory of the download. Section 2.1 has a list of dependencies required to use the package. Once you have all of that installed try the build procedure in 2.3. Once that is working try the examples per 2.7. If you have errors then, post a new question with the specific error messages you're getting.

Comment: i follow this and download all Dependencies  but The same problem Qt5GStreamer-1.0 development package not found

Comment: i add this to .pro file INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_1_61_0 &&
LIBS += "-LC:/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib"
&&
INCLUDEPATH += C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86_64/include

Comment: I don't believe that you did the build procedure in 2.3.

Comment: what the path he mean in this line cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/installation/prefix ? the src or the example or what ?

Comment: i try this in the example folder and i get  https://s14.postimg.org/mume718sx/Capture.png